# Three.js - How to rotate an object to lookAt one point and orient towards another

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm new to three.js and 3d programming in general, so this may seem like a very simple question. Ideally, I hope the answer can help me understand the underlying principles.

I have an object that needs to "point" at another point (the origin, in this case, for simplicity), which can be done easily with the `Object3D.lookAt(point)` function. This points the Z axis of the object at the point nicely.

I also want to rotate my object, called `looker`, around its Z axis such that its X axis points generally towards another object, `refObj`. I know that the X axis can't point directly at the `refObj` unless that object happens form a right angle with the origin. I want the X axis of `looker` to lie on the plane created by `origin`, `refObj` and `looker`, as diagramed below:

[image: diagram of problem]

The simplest way of doing the rotation would seem to be to modify `looker.rotation.z`, but I don't know how to calculate what the value should be.

In general, I would like an extended version of the `lookAt` function which takes a second coordinate to which the X axis would be oriented. Something like this:

```
function lookAtAndOrient(objectToAdjust, pointToLookAt, pointToOrientXTowards)
{
  // First we look at the pointToLookAt
  objectToAdjust.lookAt(pointToLookAt);

  // Then we rotate the object
  objectToAdjust.rotation.z = ??;
}
```

I have created a [jsFiddle with the example diagramed above](http://jsfiddle.net/rQasN/5/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What you are really saying is you want the y-axis of the object (the object's [`up`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.up)-vector) to be orthogonal to the plane.

All you have to do is set the object's `up`-vector before you call [`lookAt( origin )`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt).

You compute the desired `up` vector by taking a cross-product of two vectors you know lie in the plane.

three.js r.143