# Three.js - Rotation not respecting local orientation

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation, three.js

I'm using a large array of objects built around a center point in a scene, and need to manipulate them all around their local axis. They are all facing the origin using a blank object and lookAt(), then I used [this method to align the other axes correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250208/three-js-how-to-rotate-an-object-to-lookat-one-point-and-orient-towards-anothe). Getting the initial rotation this way worked great, unfortunately when I try to rotate these objects on the fly with `object.rotation.x = <amount>`, it does not respect the local axis of the object.

The confusing part is, it's not even using the global axis, the axis it's using almost seems entirely arbitrary. [I set up a JSFiddle to demonstrate this here](http://jsfiddle.net/hLgAz/1/). As you can see on line 129, `looker.rotation.z` works correctly, it rotates along the Z axis properly, but if it's changed to X or Y, it doesn't rotate along local or global axes. If anyone could demystify what is happening to cause this, that would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is happening is that you want to add some rotation to the current orientation, and setting the variable `looker.rotation.z` means other thing.

At the end, to calculate the rotation matrix of the looker, there will be something like (pseudocode: the functions are not these, but you get the idea):

```
this.matrix.multiply( makeXRotationMatrix(this.rotation.x) )
this.matrix.multiply( makeYRotationMatrix(this.rotation.y) )
this.matrix.multiply( makeZRotationMatrix(this.rotation.z) )
DrawGeometry(this.geom, this.matrix)
```

and composition of rotations are not intuitive. This is why it doesn't seem to follow any axis system.

If you want to apply a rotation in some axis to the existing matrix, it can be made with the functions `rotateX (angle)`, `rotateY (angle)`, `rotateZ (angle)`, and `rotateOnAxis (axis, angle)`. `axis` can be a `THREE.Vector3`.

Changing directly `looker.rotation.z` works because it is the nearest rotation to the geometry, and it will not be affected by the other rotations (remember that transformation matrices apply in inverse order, e.g. `T*R*G` is `R`otating the `G`eometry, and then, `T`ranslating it).

### Summary

In this case I suggest not to use the line:

```
looker.rotation.z += 0.05;
```

Use

```
looker.rotateZ (0.05);
```

or

```
looker.rotateX (0.05);
```

instead. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, was overwhelmed with some other work. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for though, thank you! I didn't know about the `rotateX`, `rotateY`, and `rotateZ` functions before.